# Salesforce - Outlook sync error

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, connect-for-outlook

I have connected my Salesforce org with outlook. Now I am trying to sync my tasks with Salesforce,  normal tasks are getting synced properly but if there are any reoccurring tasks it is throwing an error like "Cannot create recurring event...".

Am I missing something in the connection part?

Comment: have you enabled recurring events in your outlook configuration?

Comment: Yes its enabled, I'm sorry I cannot approve your edit as I lack rep points

Comment: Dont worry about the  edit approval, it would be done by admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000199018

Try checking two things:

1. Recurring events should be enabled in Outlook configuration.(which you have confirmed).
2. Enable "**Creation of Recurring Events**" from the **Activity Settings** in Salesforce.  To do this navigate to:

**Your Name** | **Setup** | **Customize** | **Activities** | **Activity Settings** | **Enable Creation of Recurring Events** | **Save**.

Comment: If it doesn't works, you can ask Salesforce Support for the solution.